# set value default codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this function (get_profile_info)

```
function get_profile_info()
{
    $this->db->where('username',$this->session->userdata('username'));
    $get_profile_info = $this->db->get('memberships');
    if($get_profile_info->num_rows() == 1){
        foreach ($get_profile_info->result() as $row)
    {
        echo $row->firstname;
        echo $row->lastname;
    }
        }   
}
```

The question is how do i put this results: firstname and lastname into input form default set_value: `echo "Firstname".form_input('firstname2');`

Comment: or how to  put a query result into a form set_value

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 foreach($get_profile_info->result() as $row)
    {
        $data = array(
              'name'        => 'firstname',
              'id'          => 'firstname',
              'value'       => $row->firstname,              
            );
        echo form_input($data);
       // do the same for lastname
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set input value of your view file like this.

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['firstname']; ?>" />
```

you have to pass data array from controller.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
function get_profile_info()  
{
    $this->db->where('username',$this->session->userdata('username'));
    $get_profile_info = $this->db->get('memberships');
    if($get_profile_info->num_rows() == 1){
        return $get_profile_info->row();      
}
function your_controller
{
     $data['row'] = get_profile_infor()

     $this->load->view("yourview",$data)
}
```

**IN View**

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo set_value('firstname',$row->firstname)?>" />
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo set_value('lastname',$row->lastname)?>" />
```