# default value in input form error

Tags: codeigniter

I have this function

```
function validate_credentials()
{
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($query)
    {
    $this->db->where('username',$this->session->userdata('username'));
    $get_profile_info = $this->db->get('memberships');
    if($get_profile_info->num_rows() == 1){
        foreach ($get_profile_info->result() as $row)
    {
        $info = array('firstname' => $row->firstname);
    }
        }
        $data = array(  
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'firstname' => $info['firstname'],
            'is_logged_in' => true
            );  
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('/site/main_menu');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

I want to put the firstname value from session to a input form default value.

```
echo "Firstname".form_input('firstname2',$this->session->userdata('firstname'));
```

But it doesn't work. It give me this error and i don't know how to solve.
Error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: You asked same kind of question few minutes before. Same answer for both questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [set value default codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876394/set-value-default-codeigniter)

Comment: kumar_v can u discuss a problem in chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass value as array.

```
echo "Firstname".form_input(array("name"=>'firstname2',"value"=>$this->session->userdata('firstname')));
```

Comment: it doesn't work. It gives me the same error and in the field appears 'array'.

Comment: Error: Array to string conversion . And it appears 'Array' in my form.

Comment: it works. Thank you! I am beginner, you must understand my idiot questions.